# Group and total of a list

Tags: text-processing

Using bash, is it possible to get a count of entries from a list, for example, for the list

```
a
b
a
cccc
b
a
```

The desired output would be something like

```
a 3
b 2
cccc 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk '{
         arr[$0]+=1
     }
     END{
         for (item in arr){
             print(item, arr[item])
         }
     }' inputfile
```

`arr` is an associative array, its key is the whole line (`$0`), its value is the number of occurrences of the key. At the end we loop over the whole array and print all keys and their values.

Comment: amazing answer!

Answer (score 5):

The usual way is to use `sort | uniq -c`.  For your example, that gives

```
  3 a
  2 b
  1 cccc
```

If you really need the count to be at the end of the line, a pass through `sed` can fix that.